# CUDA too many dlls

Tags: c++, opencv, dll, cuda

I've recently started learning image processing with opencv and cuda.
I've noticed that whenever I want to deploy my application, I need to add nearly all cuda dlls from sdk. Problem is, that those dlls are over 500 mb in size.

So, is it normal, or I'm just doing something wrong?

Comment: not the only one with that problem: https://www.freelancer.com/projects/C-Programming/opencv-reduce-size-for-CUDA/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targetting on one specific GPU you can look at **nvprune** to remove unused binary code.  http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-binary-utilities/#nvprune

I'm afraid there is no solution if you don't have a specific target.

Comment: does the size result from precompiled cuda code? Afair cuda can you either precompiled or on-first-use compilation? Is this the reason?

Comment: Since the code is compiled multiple times when you have multiple targets your library includes the binary code so it will increase if you add cuda architectures/compute capability support. i don't know CUDA when they generates code includes ptx-assembly into libraries such as nppi/nppc etc... so i don't know if the code can execute (using jit compilation) on an unknown target.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how CUDA is structured, you may very well have to include the entire thing, as you have to have the files that cover the dependencies in your own code as well as the dependencies in the DLLs that you directly need.